# Form Handler dynamic success endpoint

Tags: pardot

Can we create a dynamic success/error endpoint for form handler?
Maybe as a GET parameter, like this?

```
action="httpss://go.pardot.com/rfr/frf?success=https://myurl.com/bob/foo/123445"
```

The Pages where the user should be redirected to, are created dynamic, so we cant set a fixed one.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to specify the `success_location` URL Parameter (either a Query parameter for a Form value).

Check out https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.pardot_considerations_for_using_form_handlers.htm&type=5 for more information (under the Referrers and Errors section, you will also learn you can set `error_location` as well)